# View not being found even though it exists in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having issues with a view, other views work for me apart from this one. This is the route for it

```
Route::get('/profile/avatarupload', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getAvatarUpload',
    'as' => 'profile.avatar',
]);
```

Method in ProfileController

```
public function getAvatarUpload()
    {
        return view('profile.avatar');
    }
```

A snippet of the navbar Where I call route to it when the user clicks

```
<li><a href="{{ route('profile.avatar') }}">Update Avatar</a></li>
```

The view is in the file structure as follows `views/profile/avatarupload.blade.php`

Finally here is the error code I get when I click on Update Avatar in the navbar

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [profile.avatar] not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up route names and view names. They are not the same thing.

If your view is located at `resources/views/profile/avatarupload.blade.php`, you want to do `return view('profile.avatarupload');`

Comment: This whole time it was staring me in the face, lesson learnt. Thanks @ceejayoz